# Problem with sha pointer ["error": "--from is not a valid sha pointer: \"origin/master\"",]

Tags: git, continuous-integration, salesforce, bitbucket-pipelines, delta

I want to deploy only changed files (according to documentation: https://github.com/scolladon/sfdx-git-delta)

I add to bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
- mkdir changed-sources
- git status
- git diff YMLEdit origin/master
- sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" -f origin/master --output changed-sources/ --generate-delta
```

without git diff i receive an error:

```
sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" -f origin/master --output changed-sources/ --generate-delta
{
"error": "--from is not a valid sha pointer: \"origin/master\"",
"output": "changed-sources/",
"success": false,
"warnings": []
```

}

When I add git diff i receive this:

```
+ git diff YMLEdit origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Any ideas?

I tried using diffrent docker image
I tried using git fetch

Comment: Bitbucket is probably running your pipeline in a *shallow, single-branch* clone, so that there is no `origin/master`. Check any appropriate bitbucket documentation to find out how to direct the pipelne to use a full clone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have made the changes according to your suggestion and documntation (support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/…) added: clone: depth: full and got: + sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" -f "origin/master" --output changed-sources/ --generate-delta { "error": null, "output": "changed-sources/", "success": true, "warnings": [] }

Comment: Nice. Would you please post this comment as an answer @luk-en ? Also please expand the link to the documentation detailing the solution you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitbucket is probably running your pipeline in a shallow, single-branch clone, so that there is no origin/master.

Solution, that worked for me,
following @torek's suggestion and this documentation:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#clone

I add to bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
clone:
  depth: full

pipelines:
  default:
    # ...
```